# Is there a way to limit number of event attendees?

Tags: sharepoint-online, outlook, microsoft-teams, education

Due to the pandemic, we would like to make a calendar of lessons for students with a limited number of participants to fit in the lecture room. I would like to ask if there is a possibility to easily create an event, which you send to all students and only 10 or 15 can register, for example, then a message is displayed that the event is full.

Of course, this can be arranged by some kind of macro in Outlook, an application in PowerApps or another programmable solution. But since we have many different teachers at school with different requirements, it would be better to find a simple solution in Sharepoint (or Teams) that everyone can use individually and set their own limits and student list.

Do you know any such solution? Alternatively, can you refer me to some tip for an existing Sharepoint solution that can do this (eg something like Doodle, but inside Microsoft)? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In SharePoint, there are in fact not a quite fitting feature for your requirements. If you are not willing to set up a [room and resource mailbox](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/manage/room-and-equipment-mailboxes?view=o365-worldwide) and do it in outlook,
you may need to create an app in PowerApps integrated with SharePoint list by your own. There is a template in PowerApps called [book a room](https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/office-template-book-a-room-now-available/) which you can take as reference.